# number of tries does not increment in the PHP number-guessing game

Tags: php, html

The PHP script below is for a number-guessing game.  A hidden field is used to store the number of guesses, represented by the variable $tries.  No matter how I tried, the number of guess ($tries) never increment.  Could someone tell me what is wrong with the code please?
Maria

```
<?php
$num=21;
$tries=(isset($_POST['guess'])) ? $tries+1: 0;
if (!isset($_POST['guess'])) {
    $message="Welcome to the Guessing Game!";
} elseif (!is_numeric($_POST['guess'])) {
    $message="You need to type in a number.";
} elseif ($_POST['guess']==$num) {
    $message="You WON 1 million point!";
} elseif ($_POST['guess']>$num) {
    $message="Try a smaller number";
} else {
    $message="Try a bigger number";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Guessing Game</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><?php echo $message; ?></h1>
<p><strong>Guess number: </strong><?php echo $tries; ?></p>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
<p><label for="guess">Type your guess here:</label><br/>
<input type="text" id="guess" name="guess" />
<input type="hidden" name="tries" value="<?php echo $tries; ?>"/></p>
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$tries` is not defined when you are trying to increment it. However it is availabe in `$_POST`

```
$tries=(isset($_POST['guess'])) ? $tries+1: 0;
// Change to
$tries=(isset($_POST['guess'])) ? $_POST['tries']+1: 0;
```

Comment: I added one more variable, $prize=1000-100 * $_POST['tries'], such that if the first guess is right, the player will win $1000; if the player has a second guess, the prize will be $100 less, and so on.  This worked perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
$tries=(isset($_POST['guess'])) ? $tries+1: 0;
```

To:

```
$tries=(isset($_POST['tries'])) ? $_POST['tries']+1: 0;
```

Or, depending on the condition, only increment when a guess exists, then:

```
$tries=(isset($_POST['guess'])) ? $_POST['tries']+1: 0;
```

But doing it based on `guess` will allow the person to reset the counter by not entering a number ;)